# could Inflated layout access parent variables?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I'm new in Java/Android, so maybe my question is not clear or odd or missing some necessary information. If it is, I'll edit my question.

My questions is whether I can access isClicked variable from C.java code or not.

this is my structure of codes.

```
(P.java)
~~~~
boolean isClicked;

(P.xml)
~~~
<my_custom_class
    android:id="@+id/my_inflate_layout"
    ~~~~~~~~~~ >
</my_custom_class>


(C.xml)
normal layout code

(C.java)
public class my_custom_class extends FrameLayout implements OnClickListener {
    ~~~~~
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_guide, this);
    ~~~~~~
```

Thank you.

### Edit

I put my solution for someone who face similar question.

Child.java

```
public class Child {
    private TestListener listener; 
    public void setTestListener(TestListener l) {
        listener = l;
    }

    @Ovrride
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // when a button is clicked
       listener.clickButton(true/false);
    }


    public interface TestListener {
        public void clickButton(boolean confirm) {
        }
    }
}
```

Parent.java

```
public class Parant {
    private TestListener testListener = new TestListener() 
        @Override
        public void clickButton (boolean confirm) {
             // something want to do
        }
    };
}

Child child = (Child) findViewById(R.id.my_iniflate_layout);
child.setTestListener(testListener);
```

point is If you get ‘child’ (using Child child = (Child) findViewById(R.id.my_iniflate_layout); code)
you can access actual Child class object. After that you can use variables or methods from parent’s class through callback.

I didn’t know that. :(  (I thought that code just get some UI object or something.)

It is kinda very simple way but coult be very hard to find out to newbie because it is to simple. people who try to answer could think like ‘there is no way this guy doesn’t know about callback or sth, he must want to know some trick or other way.')

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: my inflated layout has button. I want parent class knows the button has been clicked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value from P.java can only be accessed if you have object defined from that class for if that is static and isClicked should be public.

Here is how it works in java/android.

```
//define a class
public class P{

     //public values are the one you can access from other class members
     public boolean isClicked;

    //or static but public
    public static boolean anotherIsClicked;

}
```

You can access from C.java as follows:

```
public class C{


    public void someMethod(){


        //direct access because it is public static
        P.anotherIsClicked;

        //or by creating new class
        new C().isClicked;
    }

}
```

But there are basic java stuffs error on the code. I suggest you to clearly go through java before jumping something like android UI.

Comment: Thanks. I hope I have time to study about Java and Android more but, like most of works, I have to do something while I'm not perfectly prepared. :(  But, still, thank you very much :)